# Mongodb aggregate $sample

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to retrive random data from mongodb using this code:

```
    Blog.aggregate([
        {$sample: {size: 1}}]).exec(function(err, blog){
        if(err){
        console.log(err);
        } else {

        res.render("index", {blog: blog});
        console.log(blog);
        }
    });
});
```

and my results looks like i've expected, but when i try to use my var in that way:

```
        res.render("index", {blog: blog});
        console.log(blog.title);
```

it's **undefined**

Comment: It's undefined because `blog` is an array

Answer (score 0):

Use blog[0].title, as aggregate function returns an array.

Comment: Thanks, It's just what I've been looking for.